# Why doesn't PHP support function overloading (even though it supports type hinting)?

Tags: php

Why doesn't PHP support function overloading (even though it supports type hinting)? For example why we can't do something like this:

```
function foo(Student &s)
{

}

function foo(Employee &e)
{

}
```

Comment: So, in object oriented terms those are very different methods, even if `Student` and `Employee` had a hierarchy (i.e. every employee is a student, or vice versa), one would be more restrictive than the other.  So they will be treated as two separate methods.  That's true of other OOP languages like Java and C# as well.

Comment: Because then you’d have to add runtime type information to every single instance, exploding memory usage.

Answer (score 5):

Overload resolution can be very expensive. For example, in C#, overload resolution is known to be NP-complete. In fact, it can be shown that overloading *in general*, i.e. without additional restrictions placed on the overloading itself and on the type system, is typically NP-complete. Even worse: overloading in a Hindley-Milner style type system makes the type system undecidable.

PHP does not have static typing. Therefore, overload resolution can only happen at runtime, more precisely, at call time.

Now, it is one thing if e.g. resolving a certain overload in C# takes several minutes *once*, at compile time; it is a completely different thing if something as complex as overload resolution is happening for *every single function call*, at runtime.

It would certainly be *possible* to design overloading for PHP with enough restrictions to make the resolution cheap enough that you can afford to do it for every single function call. But designing such a language feature is long, hard, and expensive, and above all, there is no guarantee that once you have restricted overloading enough to be computationally feasible, what is left is actually a useful feature.

There is a popular idea in the language design community that every language feature starts out with a score of minus 1000 points. Adding a feature to a language is a *lot* of work:

- The semantics of the feature need to be designed.
- The syntax of the feature needs to be designed.
- The interaction of this feature with the type system needs to be designed.
- The interaction of this feature with the library needs to be designed.
- Every possible interaction of this new feature with every existing language feature needs to be carefully examined, understood, and evaluated.
- Note that this means that every feature you add also makes future features *even more expensive* to add, because there will be more existing features you need to consider! So, the feature not only has a current cost but also increases future cost. So, you also need to carefully evaluate what this future cost might be.
- Every possible interaction of this new feature with every possible *future* language feature needs to be carefully examined, understood, and evaluated. You don't want to paint yourself into a corner by adding a language feature which makes it impossible to evolve your language in the future!
- It is almost impossible to change or remove language features, since this would almost always break existing code. Therefore, once a feature has been added to the language, it *cannot* be changed, it *cannot* be removed, and it *needs to be maintained forever*.
- This also means that you don't get a do-over. The feature needs be perfect *at the first try*. Which means you need to be extra-careful and diligent when considering #1–#8.
- After all this, the feature needs to be *specified*.
- The feature needs to be *documented*.
- And then, the feature needs to be *implemented*.
- The feature needs to be *tested*.

In the end, the feature needs to provide ideally several orders of magnitude more benefits than it has costs.

And it is just not clear that overloading will clear that hurdle.

Comment: Am I right to think that runtime overload resolution would be the same or similar to a double-dispatch feature?

Comment: The "minus 100 points" idea originated at Microsoft, during Eric Lippert's tenure.  See [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericgu/minus-100-points).

Comment: @bdsl Yes, but overload resolution can be much more complicated than normal dispatch because it can involve any number of parameters. And PHP's type annotations do not only describe nominal types, there can also be intersection types `A&B` to describe a combination of interfaces, and union types `A|B`. If an input value can match multiple overloads, it gets exceedingly difficult to determine which overload is the “best” match. Given that context, the best move is not to play, and to require the programmer to write the dispatch code by hand.